# How to write an `intersperse` function in Perl 6

Tags: list, raku, lazy-sequences

One thing I've been missing in Perl 6, is an `intersperse` function [like Haskell has](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse):

> The intersperse function takes an element and a list and `intersperses' that element between the elements of the list.

E.g. this:

```
intersperse <X Y>, (<a b>, <c d>, <e f>);
```

...should return this sequence:

```
<a b>, <X Y>, <c d>, <X Y>, <e f>
```

So I've been trying to implement it myself as a custom function.
For maximum re-usability, it should:

1. Support any kind of object (including List and Nil) as elements.
2. Not change the containerization of elements in any way.
3. Not flatten or otherwise affect the inner structure of elements in any way.
4. Return a lazy sequence if the input list is given as a lazy sequence, so that it can be used on infinite sequences, as in `intersperse 42, 1..Inf`.

What I've come up with so far, is this:

```
sub intersperse (\element, +list) {
    ((element xx *) Z list).map(|*)[1..*]
}
```

That is: Infinitely repeat the element to be interspersed, zip it with the list, then use `map` to `slip` each tuple so as to remove the layer of nesting added by the zip without flattening the original elements, and then use an array subscript to remove the leading repetition of the interspersed element.

It satisfies the requirements 1-3, but not 4, because the array subscript operates eagerly *(i.e. fully iterates the input sequence and then returns a non-lazy List)* and thus causes this function to hang when given an infinite sequence.

**What would be a good way to implement this function so that it satisfies all 4 requirements?**

Comment: Interesting. Kind of like a `List` version of `join`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not particularly happy with the solutions I've come up with, but here they go:

```
sub intersperse (\element, +list) {
    map { ((element xx *) Z list).map(|*)[$_] },
        1..(list.is-lazy ?? Inf !! list.elems * 2 - 1);
}
```

---

```
sub intersperse (\element, +list) {
    gather for list {
        FIRST .take, next;
        take slip element, $_;
    }
}
```

---

```
sub intersperse (\element, +list) {
    list.map({ slip element, $_ }) does role {
        method iterator {
            my \it = callsame;
            it.pull-one;
            it;
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps it'll serve as inspiration for someone else to come up with something better...

Comment: Ouch, that first one turns it from `O(n)` into `O(n²)`, doesn't it?

Comment: The `gather`/`take` one seems like a good approach though, I hadn't thought of that. 
I don't think the comma operator is guaranteed to be a sequence point like it is in C though, so I'd probably write that line something like `FIRST { take $_; next }`.

Comment: well, I wouldn't recommend the first approach: it was just what I came up with to make your original idea work; I suspect there might be a better way to do it, but it wasn't immediately obvious to me; regarding the comma operator, it should be safe as that gets evaluated left-to-right; I don't think that's actually documented anywhere - if it isn't someone should do so and add a corresponding spectest

Comment: S03 http://design.perl6.org/S03.html#Sequence_points specifically says it's erroneous to rely on sequential side-effects of operators that aren't specified as sequence points. It doesn't say which category the comma is in, but I vaguely remember Larry or someone else saying on IRC (months ago) that it's not guaranteed to be a  sequence point for now.